# HTML Email : Want to design like in the image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to get the progress image and on the same line the schedule for event.

I would like to have an output , just as in image.

[image: Here is the image]

I want the output like this.

```html
<table>
  
   <tr>
                    <td height="20" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                        <table class="bg-color1" style="width: 600px;text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr style="">
                                <td width="5%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">
                                        9:30
                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="2%" valign="top" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 10px;">

                                </td>

                                <td width="20%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;">
                                    <img src="../calender.png" width="12" height="12" style="vertical-align: middle;">

                                    <span style=" font-weight:600;font-size:12px; line-height:12px;color: white;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 24px; vertical-align:middle;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'proxima_novasemibold', Arial, sans-serif;">
                                        Day 1
                                    </span>

                                </td>

                                <td width="68%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>



                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <td height="20" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                        <table class="bg-color1" style="width: 600px;text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr style="">
                                <td width="5%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">
                                       
                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="2%" align="right" valign="middle" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 60px;">
                                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRTb.png"style="vertical-align:middle;" />
                                </td>

                                <td width="78%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">

                                    <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; Margin-left: 10px;">08 - 30 : 09 - 30 </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <span style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; Margin-left: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;"> Tea Registration & Networking </span>

                                </td>

                                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>




                <tr>
                    <td height="20" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                        <table class="bg-color1" style="width: 600px;text-align: center;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr style="">
                                <td width="5%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">
                                       
                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td width="2%" valign="top" style="mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 70px;padding-top: 10px;">
                                </td>

                                <td width="78%" style=" background: #fa4b00; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">

                                    <span  style="color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; padding-left: 10px;">9:30 - 9:40 </span><br>
                                    <span  style="color: white;text-align: left;letter-spacing:0px;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;line-height: 30px;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px; padding-left: 10px; text-transform: uppercase;"> Opening Remarks & Conference Introduction </span><br>
                                    <span style="padding-left: 10px;"><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301848.jpeg" width="25" height="25" style="border-radius:50%; border: 1px solid white; "></span>

                                </td>

                                <td width="10%" valign="top" style="border: none;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse; text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 15px;letter-spacing: 0px;vertical-align: middle;">
                                    <span style="text-align: right;">

                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

  
  </table>
```

Here is the image for progress bar.

[image: Progress bar image]

Any help would be grateful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```html
<table style="background-color:white;">
<tr>
<th style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aER9.png');background-position: center;padding-left: 60px;padding-bottom:90px;"></th>
<th style="text-align:left;"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRTb.png"><span style="background: #fa4b00;color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px;padding:20px;">Day</span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="middle" style="border:0px!important;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 60px;padding-bottom:90px;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aER9.png');background-position: center;"></td>

                                <td width="78%" style="border:0px!important;text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRTb.png">
                                    <span style="border:0px!important;background: #fa4b00;color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px;padding:20px;margin-left:-5px;">08 - 30 : 09 - 30 <br>Tea Registration & Networking </span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="2%" align="right" valign="middle" style="border:0px!important;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;mso-table-lspace:0pt;border-collapse: collapse;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 500;font-size: 18px;letter-spacing: 0px;padding-left: 60px;padding-bottom:90px;background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aER9.png');background-position: center;"></td>

                                <td width="78%" style="border:0px!important;text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'open sans', arial, sans-serif;padding-top: 0px;text-transform: uppercase;text-align: left;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLRTb.png" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                                    <span style="border:0px!important;background: #fa4b00;color: white;text-align: left;text-decoration: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;display: inline-block;text-transform:uppercase;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:10px;padding:20px;margin-left:-5px;">9:30 - 9:40 <br>Opening Remarks & Conference Introduction <br><img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301848.jpeg" width="25" height="25" style="border-radius:50%; border: 1px solid white; "></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: exactly... thank you.. but one thing is that. there is a little space between that progress image. so can it be filled? just like in the image.

Comment: Just add a `margin-top` to the Image. Like this; `<img src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws/images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301848.jpeg" width="25" height="25" style="border-radius:50%; margin-top:15px; border: 1px solid white; ">`

Answer (score 0):

First off, this isn't tabular data so [if possible don't use a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).

You can get all the design elements you need (the vertical line, the circle with a dot in the middle, and the orange triangles) with CSS alone, using pseudo-elements (see the [beginners' explanation on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) and the [more in-depth ones on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)).

The non-table thing you're looking to style is a list, so here's a solution using `<ul>`. If it's important to keep using `<table>` markup, you could adapt this CSS to fit that HTML.

Basically:

- on the container (here, `<ul>`) use a left border for the vertical line
- give each item (here, `<li>`) a `::before` pseudo-element, and use that for the circle
- give each item (here, `<li>`) an `::after` pseudo-element, and use that for the dot
- wrap the items' (here, the `<li>`s') contents in a wrapper element (here, a `<span>`) and

  - give the wrapper (here, `<span>`) a `::before` pseudo-element, and use that for the triangle
  - on the first (and optionally the last) item (here, `<li>`), give the wrapper (here, `<span>`) an `::after` pseudo-element, and use that to cover up the top (and optionally bottom) end(s) of the vertical line

Other than the pseudo-elements, the advanced parts of this CSS are the triangle and the vertically centering the circle-and-dot. Here's [a good explanation of how the triangle works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work), and [this is the method I'm using for vertical centering](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

I've left the bottom tail of the vertical line visible, but I've included the CSS necessary to cover it: just uncomment the three `li:last-child span::after`.

```css
/* the container */
.fancy-list {
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  list-style: none; /* remove the li's bullets */
  border-left: 3px solid #000; /* the vertical line */
}

/* the items */
li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fb4d00;
  color: #fff;
}

/* -- the design elements -- */

/* some shared styles for the design feature pseudo-elements
*/
/* li:last-child span::after,*/ /* covers the bottom */
li:first-child span::after, /* covers the top */
li::before, /* the circle */
li::after, /* the dot */
li span::before { /* the triangle */
  content: ''; /* pseudo-elements must always have a content property */
  position: absolute; /* so that we can position them where we want */
  display: block; /* so that we can size them */
}

/* centers vertically */
li::before, /* the circle */
li::after, /* the dot */
li span::before { /* the triangle */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* raise above the bit that covers the top and bottom of the line (styled by the z-index:0 in the "rectangles to cover up the line" section, below
*
*/
li:before, /* the circle */
li:after { /* the dot */
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* the circle */
li::before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: -54px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

/* the dot */
li::after {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  left: -45px;
  background: #000;
}

/* the triangle */
li span::before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: -10px;
  /* the makes the triangle */
  border-right: 10px solid #fb4d00;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}

/* rectangles to cover up the line
*/
/* li:last-child span::after,*/ /* covers the bottom */
li:first-child span::after { /* covers the top */
  top: 0; /* from the top of the item */
  bottom: 50%; /* to half-way down (ie. to the center of the circle and dot */
  left: -54px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 0; /* layer below the circle and dot (see line 40) */
}
/* covers the bottom */
/*
li:last-child span::after {
  top: 50%; /* from half-way down the item */
  bottom: 0; /* to the bottom */
}
*/
```

```html
<ul class="fancy-list">
  <li>
    <span>a</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      b<br>b'<br>b''
  </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>c</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
      d<br>d'<br>d''<br>d'''
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He mentioned this was an email he was designing, so he'll need to use a table. Email clients are stuck in the past.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right in the title but somehow I missed it. This def won't work for emails… guess I'll leave it here though